# Disable Button for form

Tags: javascript

I have a simple form. Ive tried to disable the the submit button until fields have been filled out, however it seems to not be working. can anyone point me in the right direction to what I'm doing wrong.

```
<form id="casmansForm">
  Name: <input type="name" id="userName" class="inputs"><br>
  Email: <input type="name" id="userName" class="inputs"><br>
  Text: <input type="name" id="userName" class="inputs"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="userSubmit" disabled><br>
</form>
<div id='alertMessage'></div>

var userName = document.getElementById('userName');
var userEmail = document.getElementById('userEmail');
var userText = document.getElementById('userText');
var userSubmit = document.getElementById('userSubmit');
var alertMessage = document.getElementById('alertMessage');

function checkForm(){
  if(userName.value == "" || userEmail.value == "" || userText.value == "") 
{
    alertMessage.innerHTML = 'Please fill in form correctly';
    userSubmit.disabled = true;
    return false;
  } else {
    alertMessage.innerHTML = 'Thank you for filling in form';
    userSubmit.disabled = false;
    return true;
  }
}

userName.addEventListener("blur",checkForm,false);
userEmail.addEventListener("blur",checkForm,false);
userText.addEventListener("blur",checkForm,false);
```

Comment: Well you have three elements with same id so I am assuming you have a copy paste error... I am also not sure what `type="name"` is

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you have used the same `id` on more than one element. `id`s must be unique within a document.

Also, `return false` is not doing anything for you in this context.

Lastly, don't use `.innerHTML` when you aren't supplying any HTML, use `textContent` for that instead.

```js
var userName = document.getElementById('userName');
var userEmail = document.getElementById('userEmail');
var userText = document.getElementById('userText');
var userSubmit = document.getElementById('userSubmit');
var alertMessage = document.getElementById('alertMessage');

function checkForm(){
  if(userName.value == "" || userEmail.value == "" || userText.value == "") {
    alertMessage.textContent = 'Please fill in form correctly';
    userSubmit.disabled = true;
  } else {
    alertMessage.textContent = 'Thank you for filling in form';
    userSubmit.disabled = false;
  }
}

userName.addEventListener("blur",checkForm,false);
userEmail.addEventListener("blur",checkForm,false);
userText.addEventListener("blur",checkForm,false);
```

```html
<form id="casmansForm">
  Name: <input type="name" id="userName" class="inputs"><br>
  Email: <input type="name" id="userEmail" class="inputs"><br>
  Text: <input type="name" id="userText" class="inputs"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="userSubmit" disabled>
</form>

<div id='alertMessage'></div>
```